# Knockout mapping plugin: make every node in hierarchical object structure observable

Tags: knockout.js, mapping, observable, hierarchical

I'm using Knockout and the ko.mapping plugin to create and to update my viewmodel. I have a json structure like this coming from the server, e.g.:

```
var viewmodel = {
    name: "Foo",
    person: {
        forename: "John",
        surname: "Smith"
    }
};
```

When I use `ko.mapping.fromJS(viewmodel)` to create my viewmodel, only the leaf nodes are converted to observables, so I get something similar to the following:

```
var viewmodel = {
    name: ko.observable("Foo"),
    person: {
        forename: ko.observable("John"),
        surname: ko.observable("Smith")
    }
};
```

But I need every property to be an observable (in this example `person` has to be an obervable too) because I have some custom bindings that can handle complex observable objects.
How can I configure the mapping plugin to convert **every** property to an observable?

I know that I can use something like this:

```
var mapping = {
    'person': {
        create: function (options) {
            var myPersonData = ko.mapping.fromJS(options.data);
            return ko.observable(myPersonData);
        }
    }
};

ko.mapping.fromJS(viewmodel, mapping);
```

but I need a dynamic solution, because I don't know the property names (e.g. "person"). The server generates a dynamic json object and returns it to the client (the HTML code with the bindings is also created dynamically with the correct property names).
The function shown above has to be executed for **every** property in the json object - is this possible? Or is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely convinced at how legitimate this is, but as a rough solution, it does appear to do what you want.

Basically, loop over all the properties on your javascript data object, check that they are your properties (using hasOwnProperty()). You then need to see what type the property is, and if it is an object, then you need to recursively call the makeObservable method, otherwise create the property as an observable.

I've not implemented all the types, only string, array and object, so you'll need to fill in the rest:

```
function makeObservable(data, viewmodel) {
    var vm = viewmodel || ko.observable({});
    for (var prop in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            var ctorType = data[prop].constructor;
            var mappedProperty;
            if (ctorType === String) {
                mappedProperty = ko.observable(data[prop]);
            } else if (ctorType === Array) {
                mappedProperty = ko.observableArray();
                for (var arr in data[prop]) {
                    if (data[prop].hasOwnProperty(arr)) {
                        mappedProperty.push(makeObservable(data[prop][arr]));
                    }
                }
            } else if (ctorType === Object) {
                mappedProperty = makeObservable(data[prop]);
            }

            if (ko.isObservable(vm)) {
                vm()[prop] = mappedProperty;
            } else {
                vm[prop] = mappedProperty;
            }
        }
    }
    return vm;
}

var viewModel = makeObservable(data, {});
```

I've also create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7RJL/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer! Yes it would work - but then I have to implement the update function as well and I have to take care of all the different types and special cases. I was hoping to use the mapping plugin and configure it instead of implementing all the functionality myself (I'm not sure if this implementation really covers every use case, because the mapping plugin has about 800 lines of tested code for nearly the same functionality).